I am getting this error while cloning WhiteSur-gtk-theme
Cloning into 'WhiteSur-gtk-theme'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 16799, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2693/2693), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1109/1109), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 8108 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Why am I getting this and help me fix the issue please.

It seems that the internet connection is unstable. Please use a different connection and try again.
